# Excel Need to copy certain items descriptions from one file to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy, spreadsheet

I looked and didn't find any answer.  I have 2 spreadsheets. One has 7,000 items the other has 2,000. I need to copy the description of the parts listed in the second spreadsheet from the first on to the second. Below is an example.

```
Item    Description    *other-field*    *other-field*    *other-field*
#8402   example des.   example text     example text     example text     
#0383   example des.   example text     example text     example text     
#8932   example des.   example text     example text     example text     
#9275   example des.   example text     example text     example text     
#8735   example des.   example text     example text     example text     
                             and 7,000 more under
```

so this would be sheet one.  I need to have a formula that takes the description of the items listed in sheet two(example below) and copy them from sheet1 to sheet2.

```
 Item    Description    *other-field*    *other-field*   
#0383       no des.      example text     example text  
#8735       no des.      example text     example text     
#9275       no des.      example text     example text      
                                 and many more
```

So I need a formula that searches column 1 from sheet2 in sheet1 and copy's description for the ones it finds match. and transfers description to the items in sheet2

Edit:

One question: my second sheet is on a different file is there a way to permanently transfer this information? Because if I delete the 7,000 list the descriptions on my 2,000 will dissapear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VLOOKUP function to search a value from the Sheet1 into a range of cells in Sheet2 and the result will be the matching value on column 2 of the range:

```
Item    Description
#8402   =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
#0383   =VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
#8932   =VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
#9275   =VLOOKUP(A5,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
#8735   =VLOOKUP(A6,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

If Sheet2 is on a different file you must use something like `'[excel.xls]Sheet2'!$A$1:$B$4` inside the formulas. It may vary depending on the file path.

Comment: Ok thanks I realized if you copy and paste the formula it auto changes the "A2"  field to the one it's at. Works perfectly for what I need thank you so much. God Bless You.

Comment: One question: my second sheet is on a different file is there a way to pernamently transfer this information? Because if I delete the 7,000 list the descriptions on my 2,000 will dissapear. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I actually fixed that by coping all the descriptions and then Paste Special and paste value. Thanks God Bless You.